# Markov chains - transition matrix - probabilty formula and application help?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider the $3\times3$ transition matrix

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  &A &B &C \\
\hline
A &0.2 & 0.3 &0.5\\
B &0.3 & 0.5 &0.2\\
C &0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4
\end{array}.
$$
Given that the chain starts in state $B$ what is the probability that after three transitions it is back in state $B$ having visited $A$ and $C$?

I have a few exam paper questions similar to this but I can only find one sort of formula related to this in my notes and it's not very clear and no examples. I was wondering if someone could give me a formula for these types of problems and show me how to apply it to this question and how to use it for others?

Many thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$B\Rightarrow C\Rightarrow A\Rightarrow B$$
$$P(x_0=B,x_1=C,x_2=A,x_3=B)=P(x_0=B)\ P(x_1=C|x_0=B)$$
$$\qquad \qquad \qquad P(x_2=A|x_1=C)\ P(x_3=B|x_2=A)$$
$$P(x_0=B,x_1=C,x_2=A,x_3=B)=1\times 0.2\times 0.3\times 0.3=0.018$$
or
$$B\Rightarrow A\Rightarrow C\Rightarrow B$$
$$P(x_0=B,x_1=A,x_2=C,x_3=B)=P(x_0=B)\ P(x_1=A|x_0=B)$$
$$\qquad \qquad \qquad P(x_2=C|x_1=A)\ P(x_3=B|x_2=C)$$
$$P(x_0=B,x_1=A,x_2=C,x_3=B)=1\times 0.3\times 0.5\times 0.3=0.045$$
and in total
$$P=0.063$$
-----------Transition Matrix------------
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  &A &B &C \\
\hline
A &P(A|A) &P(B|A) &P(C|A)\\
B &P(A|B) &P(B|B) &P(C|B)\\
C &P(A|C) &P(B|C) &P(C|C)
\end{array}
which means if you select (2,1) it means that you look up for the probability of transition from B to A. Rows are for current state and columns for next state.

Comment: So say a chain starts in state C what is the probability that after two transitions it is in A?

Comment: I meant to add:
$C \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$ or $C \rightarrow A \rightarrow A$ or $C \rightarrow C \rightarrow A$

So taking the first one:

$P(x_0 = C)P(x_1 = B |x_0 = C)P(x_2 = A | x_1 = B)P(x_0=C, x_1 = B, x_3 = A)$ I guess what I'm asking is where are the numbers coming from. I'm a little confused. Thanks :)

Comment: @Swayy check for edit.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much! :)